# How can I return a generic list from memory cache

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a class that mainly works around memory cache. I have a function that reads from the cache. How can I return a generic list, so that I can cast according to class type?

```
private ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default; 
public List<T> GetCachedDataList<T>(string key)
{
    List<T> result = null;
    if (cache.Contains(key))
        result = cache[key] as List<T>;
    return result;
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
List<HelloClass> data = GetCachedDataList<HelloClass>("HelloString") as List<HelloClass>;
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: don't see any issue with this other than I would change the line `List<T> result = null;` to `List<T> result = new List<T>();` so you are returning an empty list on error rather than null and you don't need another `as List<HelloClass>;` after the function call as it's already cast

Comment: In your last code sample, you don't need the `as List<HelloClass>`, the function already returns the correct type.

Comment: function looks good, but you dont need to do this statement GetCachedDataList<HelloClass>("HelloString") as List<HelloClass>; function already returns a list.

Comment: @MarcoFatica In this case it'd only mean you don't realize you got a cache miss. At least with a null return value you're bound to get an exception at some point. I'd say either keep returning null or throw on cache miss. I'm kinda torn about the method overall though. Right now it's a wrapper for a typecast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method already returns typed list then yod don't need to cast it againg. Just use your code without casting:

```
List<HelloClass> data = GetCachedDataList<HelloClass>("HelloString");
```

To use more generic solution you can implement next method:

```
public T GetCachedData<T>(string key)
{
    try
    {
        if (cache.Contains(key))
            return (T) cache[key];
        return default(T);
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException ex)
    {
        // We can't return null because T can be value type
        // then returns default value for T. For classes it will be null.
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this method for more scenarios:

```
List<HelloClass> data = GetCachedData<List<HelloClass>>("HelloString");
HelloClass data = GetCachedData<HelloClass>("HelloStringSingleValue");
```

Comment: What is the best way to return a single object instead of list of objects?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. If you added a single object you can create similar generic method `GetCachedData<T>` where you will try to cast cached data to `T'` and use it like `GetCachedData<HelloClass>("SingleValue")`. More of this you can use it instead of `GetCachedDataList` in this case `GetCachedData<List<HelloClass>>("HelloString")`

Comment: I am getting error "The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class'.    I am using this function     `    public T GetCachedData<T>(string key)
        {
            T result = default(T);
            if (cache.Contains(key))
                result = cache[key] as T;
            return result;
        }`

Comment: Yes it's because as-operator is valid only for classes. I updated my answer with whole code.

Comment: What worries me is that you cover up the case when there's something wrong in the cache. If I store a `string` under a given key and want an `int` back, I really want to know that I did something wrong instead of having `default(int)` (=0) returned as if everything was right.